# Azure DevOps agent cannot write to UNC path when Service Account is in a Group

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, file-permissions

### The Problem

When executing my Release Pipeline, I cannot copy a file to a UNC path unless the service account the agent is running under has DIRECT R/W permissions on the destination share. Since we manage permissions using AD groups, adding the service account to several folders in many locations is not scalable nor maintainable. If the service account is a part of a group that has R/W permission to the share, the pipeline **fails**.

### Pipeline Code

I have release pipeline that deployed via Self-Hosted agent. The agent is running under the account `MYDOMAIN\SRVACCOUNT`. The pipeline has the following Powershell Task step:

```
Write-Host "User running the script is: $([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)"

$path = "\\server\share\myfolder"
New-Item -Path $path -Name "testfile1.txt" -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a text string." -Force
```

The pipeline fails on the PowerShell task and says:
`New-Item : Access to the path '\\server\share\myfolder\testfile1.txt' is denied`

[image]

From the logs, it says `User running the script is 'MYDOMAIN\SRVACCOUNT'`, so I assume that it must be running under the correct credentials.

Picture of Windows Service running on the self-hosted agent:

[image: WindowsServices]

### Group Permissions

User `MYDOMAIN\SRVACCOUNT` is a part of the group `MYDOMAIN\APP_ADMINS` which has Full Control to the UNC folder path.

- When the user is a part of the group the pipeline fails.
- When the user is assigned DIRECT Full-Control access, the pipeline success.

When I log as this service account, I can navigate to the folder just fine and create files whether the user has group or direct permissions to the shares.

[image: CreatedFile]

---

Would someone be able to educate me why Azure DevOps pipelines fails in R/W permissions to a UNC path when the user is assigned to a group rather than being directly assigned to the folder?

Answer (score 0):

After assigning permissions to the service account, you must restart the Azure DevOps agent on the server (or just restart the server). For some reason, it seems that the permissions/access to the resources is cached at the time the Azure DevOps Windows Service is started up, so restarting it after allocating the new permissions will allow it to work.